# ForeignObject text not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used ForeignObject order to wrap some text. For some apparent reason it isn't appearing on the canvas at all. I'm probably missing something, but I can't see what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
 var blah = { "Lets see how long this goes on for!!!": "translate(-150,20)"

        };

var dah = [ {name:"Lets see how long this goes on for!!!"} ]; 


var fo = svg.append("svg:foreignObject")
         .data(dah)
         .enter()
         .attr("width", 80)
         .attr("height", 200)
         .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return blah[d.name];})

fo.append("xhtml:chart")
  .html(function(d) {d.name;})
  .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")

 ;
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/44/

Comment: Since this seems to be a "visual" problem, please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for us to play around with. This enables us to help you faster and potentially creates more accurate/helpful answers.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I edited the original question. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
var fo = svg.append("svg:foreignObject")
            .data(dah)
            .enter()
            .attr("width", 80)
```

The interpreter complains

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'attr'
```

Because the `attr` method operates on transitions and **selections**. Before using it, it's necessary to enter a selection. Modify your code to the following and append text to the `foreignObject` using the `text` method.

```
var fo = svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
            .data(dah)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 80)
            .attr("height", 200)
            .text(function(d) { return d.t; });
```

updated JS: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/xwZjN/46/

Also, you might want to use only one data object, instead of this

```
var blah = { "Network": "translate(-150,20)"};
var dah = [ {t:"Network"}];
```

do something like this

```
var someData = [ 
    { text:"Network", translate:"translate(-150,20)"},
    { text:"Test", translate:"translate(-115,-75)"}
];
```

And operate on the data like this

```
.attr("transform", function(d,i) {return d.translate; })
.text(function(d) { return d.text; });
```

Of course you might also want to compute transformations for `foreignObject` elements programmatically.